# I want to open any thirdparty application related to Hotel Booking like MakeMyTrip through my application

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to open any thirdparty application related to Hotel Booking ( like MakeMyTrip ) through my application.

If any one implemented any please help

Comment: check this by setting custom url you can set..http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, URL Schemes are the only way to communicate between apps.

```
NSURL *Url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Type your application url here"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:Url];
```

Comment: Yes.. But how to get URL Scheme for such application. So that I can test if application is installed on device then open related app or open website.

Answer (score 0):

You can do,

```
NSURL* makeMyTripURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"makemytrip://"];
NSURL* appStoreURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/makemytrip-flights-hotels/id530488359?mt=8"];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:makeMyTripURL])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:makeMyTripURL];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:appStoreURL];
}
```